# Did Tony lie about his father's death?

Tags: plot-explanation, scarface

At the beginning of Scarface, Tony claims his father has died- yet he says the same about his mother and we later learn that was a falsehood when he visits her home.

Is it possible he lied about his father dying too?

Comment: Yes, in the movie it is revealed that his American father abandoned the family while Tony was a child.

Answer (score 1):

Their father abandoned the family. [From the script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Scarface.html):

> GINA: Tony-.-Mama -- **since Papa took off**....
>
> TONY: Hey forget Papa, we never had one, okay? He was a bum!

The scene in the movie is slightly different from the script, but conveys the same content:

> GINA: [I'm sorry. I don't know. Mama, **ever since Papa left** she's...](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/c6d877cf-cae4-4233-bbc1-4e61c7e55d9f)
>
> TONY: [Forget Papa. We never had one.](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/ab92cbd9-1881-466c-b11c-9c7ce67e918b)

(The link for each line shows the relevant clip from the movie.)

Answer (score 1):

In Tony's mind, his father is dead.  Maybe not "dead" as in "not alive", but more like the position some people take when they're angry with someone and say, "That person is dead to me".  Whether they're actually alive or not doesn't matter, you just no longer refuse to recognize their existence.

I believe when Tony said his mother was dead, he was doing so to protect her.  Much like Spider Man must remain anonymous to protect MJ and his Aunt May.  If the wrong people know she's alive, they might go looking for her.